# Combining evidence from different sources

Tags: probability, bayesian, similarities

I am computing similarities between words using similarity measures based on wordnet. I have obtained similarity measures for two words using three different methods - JNC (Jiang and Conrath), BNP (Banerjee and Pederson) and LIN (Lin). These similarity measures give values between 0 and 1 for two words (1 for exactly similar words).

I need to combine the similarity measures from the above three methods, so that I can get a better measure of similarity. I want to combine the results because   each of them has a drawback, and combining them would give a better measure.

Any ideas on how I can do that? I read about [Dempster-Shafer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dempster%E2%80%93Shafer_theory), but I want to use some other approach, because I'm finding it difficult to understand and apply it according to my requirement.

Comment: This is too general to allow good answers. People in this field will surely want to know (a) what you are doing precisely? (b) what do you mean by "more robust"? (c) why not Dempster-Shafer?

Comment: @NickCox : Thanks for your comment. I've edited the question. I hope looks better now

Answer (score 1):

Disclaimer: I am not a statistician, nor do I have much experience in this general field; I would rather have made a comment, but I don't have enough reputation.

Have you considered using a probability model akin to the one used in MYCIN? Here are two papers I found via Google:

http://aitopics.org/sites/default/files/classic/Buchanan/Buchanan13.pdf

http://aitopics.org/sites/default/files/classic/Buchanan/Buchanan14.pdf

Number 15 is about the Dempster-Shafer theory, just in case you're interested. I would like to give you the link, but I don't have enough reputation for that either. ;-)

Comment: The above links no longer work. The following appears to be the same referenced paper: https://aitopics.org/download/classics:70E56E0E